# Building a proxy servlet for web services

Tags: java, web-services, proxy

I need to create a proxy between web service clients and the services themselves which reside in different platforms. The intention is to do some validations on certain XML nodes before passing the request to the real service. Should the validations succeed, the client will receive the answer as it does today without noticing the proxy's existence.

The platform it will run on is a java server so my first thought is to build a servlet to do the task. I'll start running some testing code tomorrow but I'd appreciate any hints on how to implement this beforehand.

Comment: Do you have access to the application's source code and is it written using JAX-WS?

Comment: Yes I do and it's JAX-WS.

Comment: In my opinion you should write the validator as a SOAPHandler. SOAPHandler is much easier to implement and maintain than a servlet based soap proxy. If SOAPHandler is not an option (you have numerous services or you prefer separating the validation for security reasons), you might want to consider implementing the proxy using JAX-WS provider interface.

Comment: I might be wrong but I think SOAPHandler is not an option if the "real" web services are running in platforms other than its own.

Comment: Right, you can only use SOAPHandlers in Java services.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a pseudo-code for JAX-WS provider based proxy/gateway:

```
@WebServiceProvider
public class ServiceGateway implements Provider<SOAPMessage> {
    private static final QName SERVICE_NAME = new QName("http://ws.com",
            "Service");
    private static final QName PORT_NAME = new QName("http://ws.com", "Port");
    private static final String FAULT_MESSAGE = "fault.message";
    private static final Service service = Service.create(SERVICE_NAME);

    @Override
    public SOAPMessage invoke(SOAPMessage inboundMessage) {
        Dispatch<SOAPMessage> dispatch = service.createDispatch(PORT_NAME,
                SOAPMessage.class, Mode.MESSAGE);
        dispatch.getRequestContext().put(
                BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY,
                "http://real.destination.address");
        // Handler is required to pass SOAPFault messages
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        List<Handler> handlers = new ArrayList<Handler>(dispatch.getBinding()
                .getHandlerChain());
        handlers.add(new SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>() {
            @Override
            public void close(MessageContext context) {
            }

            @Override
            public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext context) {
                context.put(FAULT_MESSAGE, context.getMessage());
                context.setScope(FAULT_MESSAGE, Scope.APPLICATION);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext context) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
                return null;
            }
        });
        dispatch.getBinding().setHandlerChain(handlers);

        try {
            return dispatch.invoke(inboundMessage);
        } catch (SOAPFaultException exception) {
            return (SOAPMessage) dispatch.getResponseContext().get(
                    FAULT_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
}
```